# Dashboard with re-arrangeable dashboard elements in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, user-controls, dashboard

I need to create a dashboard with re-arrangeable/re-positionable dashboard elements (similar to iGoogle) using Silverlight. The dashboard elements are typically tables of data. The user should be able to dynamically add and remove dashboard elements. The user should also be able to use drag and drop to reposition the dashboard elements.

I've been looking around for Silverlight controls which I can reuse but haven't found any yet. Any ideas? Or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used the blacklight solution suggested by bruce. It is good but fairly limited. Support is also quite poor - this is a free control after all!!

Would suggest you take a serious look at the tile control from Telerik too: http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/tileview.aspx and http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/beta/#TileView/FirstLook

Answer (score 1):

Infragistics [xamWebTileView](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/xamwebtileview.aspx#Overview) for Silverlight might be what you are looking for.